# angularjs ui-select bind to an array

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I am using angularjs ui-select, 
as I understand in binds by default the multiple dropdown to an array which is what I need, problem is that I need to have the same behaviour to the single select too.

```
$scope.mdf.options = [{ id: 1, name: 'name1' },{ id: 2, name: 'name2' }];

<ui-select ng-model="wrap.piece.original.selections_hash[mdf.id]"  close-on-select="false" title="mdf.modifier.display" ng-if="mdf.modifier.max == 1">
    <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="option.id as option in mdf.options">
            <span ng-bind="option.name">
            </span>
        </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

So when user selects name2 for example I need my model to updated to [2] instead of 2.
How can I achieve that ? Can I do it with ui-select ? if not can I do it with angular select ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a key property binding.
Maybe this will help you with it. ["Example key binding"](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/demo-object-as-source.html)

Here is the code from the plunker (from the example site):

```
  <ui-select ng-model="ctrl.person.selectedSingleKey" theme="select2" ng-disabled="ctrl.disabled" style="min-width: 300px;" title="Choose a person">
     <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a person in the list or search his name/age...">{{$select.selected.value.name}}</ui-select-match>
     <ui-select-choices repeat="person.key as (key, person) in ctrl.peopleObj | filter: { value: { name: $select.search }}">
  <div ng-bind-html="person.value.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
  <small>
    email: {{person.value.email}}
    age: {{person.value.age}}
  </small>
</ui-select-choices>
```